# how to make scrollView behind navigation bar

Tags: swift, scrollview, navigationbar

How to make scrollView work behind navigation bar in swift?

In default setting, when I tap action to hide navigation bar, scrollView slide to up. I want the scrollView keep stay when hiding navigation bar.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the scrollView content inset, when you're hiding the bar:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```